# Cannot Recieve Request Parameter in Symfony2 Angular2

Tags: php, angular, symfony

problem

> i tried with $request->request->all() //var_dump output:array(0){}

symfony code

```
public function registerAction(Request $request) {

   var_dump($request->request->all());die;
  }
```

Angular2 service

```
export class UserRegistrationService {

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

 private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'});
 private insertdataUrl = 
'http://localhost/abc/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/register-user';


 /* create new user */
create(name: string): Promise<UserDetails> {

    return this.http
    .post(this.insertdataUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json().data as UserDetails)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

FormData

> {"name{"email":"abc@gmail.com","username":"abc","password":"**","repeatpassword":"**"}}:

solution that works

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

// able to get paramters //get,or //post

can anyone suggest why request doesn't print some values.

- here im posting form from angular2.

Comment: Serialize you data rather than json encoding it

Answer (score 1):

Symfony uses different containers for Post and Get. Try this way.

```
# Post
$request->request->all()

# Get
$request->query->all()
```

Comment: "Chrome DevTools -> Network -> Request Payload" what you see in the field. Looks like the problem is not in the symfony.

Comment: data is posted ok:{"name{"email":"abc@gmail.com","username":"abc","password":"","repeatpassword":""}}:

Answer (score 0):

solution that worked for me

i changed headers

from

```
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'});
```

To

```
 private headers=new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
```

- now im able to recieve data.